# Export and Import of an organisation in Jasper

Tags: jasperserver, adhoc

I was wondering if there are any options to export entities / configuration from Jasper. As Jasper doesn’t have an option to disable data sources, I am considering the possibility of backing up / exporting selected entities from Jasper and then delete them.

Later I can use the backup to import the entities if required in future.

I am considering the following items.

Data source
Ad-hoc Views
Ad-hoc Reports

Basically, I want to backup everything under an organization.

Comment: What version of Jasperserver do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I think from Jasperserver 6.3.0(maybe some earlier version) jasperadmin can export entire organization.
This is from the doc:

> To export organizations:
>
> 1. Log in as an administrator that has access to the organizations you want to export. For example, to move an organization, you must log in as the administrator of the parent organization.
> 2. Select Manage > Organizations to display the hierarchy of organizations.
> 3. In the left-hand panel, right-click the organization you want to export and select Export from the context menu.